# Will a TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW annotated method run on a new Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions, jta

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html), in container managed transactions, if a method is annotated with  `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` attribute, will suspend any client transaction, delegate the call to this method/ create a new transaction, and resume to previous transactions after the new one has been completed.

So this actually means, that no new thread is created, and that the previous transaction is on a "wait" state until the new one is has been finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [Java-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRES_NEW):

> If a client calls with a transaction context, the container suspends the association of the transaction context with the current thread before starting the new transaction and invoking the method. The container resumes the suspended transaction association after the method and the new transaction have been completed.

It's not abandoning the thread or creating a new one, it's only releasing the association to the transaction and recreating it afterwards. If it would create a new thread, there would be no need to remove the association because it was never made.

Comment: So this means that the old transaction is blocked/waiting until the new one gets completed, right?

Comment: exactly, it will be continued once the new transaction finishes.

Comment: Just to mention a common misunderstanding to this: It might be possible or it is highly probable, that the suspended transaction (if there is any) will not "see" any changes done by the "REQUIRES_NEW"-Transaction, after the return of the method.

Answer (score 2):

`Container managed transactions` means `JTA` and `JTA` specifications does not allow transactions to span across multiple threads. Each JTA transaction is associated with an execution thread, so it means that *at most one transaction can be active at any given time*. Note that multiple transactions can be associated with a single thread, but again only one can ever be active at a given time.

As `JTA` does not support nested transactions, it means that if one transaction is active, it is not possible to start another one in the same thread, until the first transaction commits or rolled back (or timed out, causing again rollback), thus releasing transaction association with the current thread.

What happens behind the scenes when method with transactional attribute `REQUIRES_NEW` is called with the transactional context? First, JTA temporarily suspends the transaction that is currently associated with the calling thread by calling it is internal API, particularly it calls `TransactionManager.suspend()`. (If calling thread is not associated with any transaction (i.e. method was called with transactional attribute of `NOT_SUPPORTED` or without transactional context) a null object reference is returned) and obtaining `Transaction` object. This `Transaction` object  will be passed to `TransactionManager.resume()` method to re-associate the transaction context with the calling thread once above mentioned `REQUIRES_NEW` method completes. Whether on same or another thread depends on JTA implementation, as specification does explicitly require it to be one way or the other.

Answering your question - the only way for JTA to fulfill transactional attribute `REQUIRES_NEW` when called in transactional context is to suspend the transaction from a thread and resume it later on the same or another thread.  When it will be resumed? Remember that `REQUIRES_NEW` attribute basically means is that annotated method always *have to be in its OWN TRANSACTION,*  which in turn means that the *method should be committed or rolled back independently of methods further up the call stack.* Suspended transaction will be resumed, once called method with transactional attribute `REQUIRES_NEW` commits or rolled back.

As a side notes, as you may probably know, there is no way for `Bean Managed Transaction` to suspend a transaction, you can't do it programatically.  Only JTA can do this using an it's internal transaction management API and you can achieve this declaratively by using `CMT` and transaction attributes. Also note that this attribute can lead to excessive transaction overheads is overused.